# .htaccess Remove trailing / unless directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess so far:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php

## REMOVE TRAILING /
#if its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#and it has a trailing slash then redirect to URL without slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have the structure like this:

```
https://example.com/page-name
```

Which returns to `index.php` as a string query, in this case it would be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'page-name'`

For SEO and canonical reasons I want to redirect the trailing / with a 301 redirect like this:

If they type in:

`https://example.com/page-name/`

Should redirect to

`https://example.com/page-name`

My current .htaccess redirects to `https://example.com/index.php` if they type in a trailing / and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reorder your rules, keep your External RewriteRules (Rules with R flag) before internal ones,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R]
#other rules
```